# Setting a clause for cross join (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am looking to show a mutual friends function but my user friends list is stored on another table.

I want to know if it's possible to use the data of each row as a clause for join B

```
SELECT * FROM (  SELECT * FROM `users`) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS MUTUAL_FRIENDS  
FROM `user_friends` WHERE `friend_to` = `a`.`userid`)  b
ORDER BY `b`.`MUTUAL_FRIENDS` ASC
```

What I am looking to do is use the *userid* from users table as a clause for the join with:

```
`friend_to` = `a`.`userid`
```

Expected results:

```
+--------=+---------+-----------+--------------+
| userid  | Username |Photo_URL |MUTUAL_FRIENDS|
+---------+---------+-----------+--------------+
   1       Somename1  /image1.png      3
   4       Somename4  /image4.png      2
   2       Somename2  /image2.png      1
   3       Somename3  /image3.png      0
   5       Somename5  /image5.png      0
```

Friends table:

```
+--------=+---------+-----------+
| friend_id | userid  |friend_to |
+---------+---------+-----------+
   1         1          2
   2         2          1
   3         1          3
   4         3          1
   5         1          4
   6         4          1
```

Users Table

```
+--------=+---------+-----------+
| userid  | Username |Photo_URL |
+---------+---------+-----------+
   1       Somename1  /image1.png
   2       Somename2  /image2.png
   3       Somename3  /image3.png
   4       Somename4  /image4.png
   5       Somename5  /image5.png
```

Or am I doing this totaly wrong?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Updated this thanks.

Comment: Hope you don't mind my change to the sample data. Can you add the expected result too?

Comment: Yeah, I have added this too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.

With `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT u.userid,u.Username,u.Photo_URL,IFNULL(Num,0) MUTUAL_FRIENDS
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid, COUNT(*) Num
FROM (SELECT a.userid
FROM Friends a
CROSS JOIN Friends b
WHERE a.userid = b.friend_to and a.friend_to = b.userid) r
GROUP BY userid) k ON u.userid = k.userid
ORDER BY MUTUAL_FRIENDS DESC, u.userid
```

Without `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT u.userid,u.Username,u.Photo_URL,IFNULL(Num,0) MUTUAL_FRIENDS
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid, COUNT(*) Num
FROM (SELECT a.userid 
FROM Friends a, Friends b
WHERE a.friend_to = b.userid and b.friend_to = a.userid) r
GROUP BY userid) k ON u.userid = k.userid
ORDER BY MUTUAL_FRIENDS DESC, u.userid
```

I will try to explain little by little and please correct me if there is error.

1. The condition `a.friend_to = b.userid and b.friend_to = a.userid` is
   used to select only mutual friend. Then if a user has this kind of
   "mutual connection," the corresponding `userid` will appear once.
2. Get the count along with the userid.
3. Left join the userid and count table.

**Result**

```
userid  Username    Photo_URL   MUTUAL_FRIENDS
1   Somename1   /image1.png 3
2   Somename2   /image2.png 1
3   Somename3   /image3.png 1
4   Somename4   /image4.png 1
5   Somename5   /image5.png 0
```

Given the data, user1 is mutual friend of user2, user3 and user4. User2 is only mutual friend of user 1 and so as user 3 and user4.

[With CROSS JOIN SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98f06aa/15)

[Without CROSS JOIN SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98f06aa/11)